# Python matplotlib how to supress float in scientific notation to save space for ylabel

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I have the code working very fine. But  I only want to display scientific notation with no decimals or floats. So that I can save space for ylabel. Below is a screenshot of a subplot. You can see here the ylabel entered into a neighbor subplot. Here, if I can supress y ticks [0.5,0.0,-0.5,-1.0..] format to this format [,0,,-1,-2..].

[image]

My code:

```
ax[frow,col].ticklabel_format(axis='y',style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier with `tight_layout`?

Comment: Though I see a lot of white space. But it is okay. `tight_layout` solved my problem.